# I can t use SessionService class in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-web-api

I have a class derived from webapi controller.In that controller i have a method

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("MessageCount")]
    public string GetMessageCountCount()
    {
        OrganisationMembership organisationMembership = organisationService.Find(organisationId);
        SessionService.Get.SetUserConversationMessages(organisationMembership);

        return SessionService.Get.UnreadMessagesCount.ToString();
    }
```

Here is SessionService

```
public class SessionService : ISessionService
{
    private static SessionService _sessionService;
    public static SessionService Get
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionService == null)
            {
                _sessionService = new SessionService(new RakletDb());
            }
            return _sessionService;
        }
    }

    public int UnreadMessagesCount
    {
        get { return GetSessionInt("UnreadMessagesCount"); }
        private set { SetSessionValue("UnreadMessagesCount", value); }
    }

    private int GetSessionInt(string key)
    {
        var s = HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
        if (s != null)
        {
            return Int32.Parse(s.ToString());
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private void SetSessionValue(string key, object o)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = o;
    }

    public void SetUserConversationMessages(OrganisationMembership organisationMembership)
    {
        this.UnreadMessagesCount = somelinq query;
    }
}
```

My project succesfully compiled. But when i call GetMessageCount method from browser it gives me an error like this:

**error**

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":" at Services.SessionService.SetSessionValue(String key, Object o)...

I use something like this in a controller :`SessionService.UnreadMessageCount` 
But in webapi I can only use `SessionService.Get.UnreadMessageCount`
so what problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on `HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = o;`,Because REST web api by design is stateless. So Default you can't use Session.

I would not suggest you use session on web api.

If you want to use Session,you need to make a `HttpHandler` which's implement `IHttpHandler` and let it implement `System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState`.

You might be like

```
public class SessionHander : 
    System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler, 
    System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
    public SessionHander(RouteData routeData) : base(routeData)
    { }
}

public class SeesionRouterHanlder : 
    System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new SessionHander(requestContext.RouteData);
    }
}
```

And this code on `Global.asax`

```
var route = RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

route.RouteHandler = new SeesionRouterHanlder();
```